# View in order to reflect the structure of this json

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, view

This is my json:

```
{              
                    "ItemCode": "NEWZTN109314",
                    "ItemName": "STAFFA SGNACIO RAPIDO ANTENNA NAV900",
                    "CodeBars": "2000000100227",
                    "WhsCode": "M1"
                    "Bin":[
                    {
                        "AbsEntry": 1,
                        "BinCode": "M1-SYSTEM-BIN-LOCATION",
                        "OnHandQty": "-2"
                    },
                    {
                        "AbsEntry": 6,
                        "BinCode": "M1-F-01-A1-01",
                        "OnHandQty": "250"
                    },
                    {
                        "AbsEntry": 7,
                        "BinCode": "M1-F-01-A1-02",
                        "OnHandQty": "250"
                    }
                    ]
}
```

The table ad fields is:

```
CREATE VIEW "MyVie"( "AbsEntry",
     "BinCode",
     "ItemCode",
     "ItemName",
     "CodeBars",
     "OnHandQty",
     "WhsCode" ) AS SELECT
 "OBIN"."AbsEntry",
     "OBIN"."BinCode",
     "OIBQ"."ItemCode",
     "OITM"."ItemName",
     "OITM"."CodeBars",
     "OIBQ"."OnHandQty",
     "OIBQ"."WhsCode" 
FROM "OBIN" 
INNER JOIN "OIBQ" ON "OBIN"."AbsEntry"="OIBQ"."BinAbs" 
INNER JOIN "OITM" ON "OITM"."ItemCode"="OIBQ"."ItemCode"
```

What changes should I do to be able to reflect that pattern?

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and support for JSON is highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using as well? When you say reflect that pattern, do you mean you want to generate JSON using T-SQL?

Comment: No I would like to create a view that reflects the json

Comment: What do you mean "reflects"? What would your result look like then? Include your expected results in your question.

Comment: I wanted to know if it was possible to create a view whose structure was like that of the json

Comment: Look into this maybe? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Please post the structure of your 3 tables (OIBQ, OITM, OBIN) with sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to generate the nested JSON you posted you must use a `JOIN` statement (more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-nested-json-output-with-path-mode-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)).

To use a join you must have two views/tables. A *quick & dirty* solution is to self join the view you already have (`MyVie`) and then extract a JSON output with `FOR JSON AUTO`:

```
select A.ItemCode, A.ItemName, A.CodeBars, A.WhsCode, 
       Bin.AbsEntry, Bin.BinCode, Bin.OnHandQty
from MyVie A 
inner join MyVie Bin on A.AbsEntry = Bin.AbsEntry 
      and A.BinCode = Bin.BinCode 
      and A.ItemCode = Bin.ItemCode
for json auto, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Output:

```
{
  "ItemCode": "NEWZTN109314",
  "ItemName": "STAFFA SGNACIO RAPIDO ANTENNA NAV900",
  "CodeBars": "2000000100227",
  "WhsCode": "M1",
  "Bin": [
    {
      "AbsEntry": 1,
      "BinCode": "M1-SYSTEM-BIN-LOCATION",
      "OnHandQty": "-2"
    },
    {
      "AbsEntry": 6,
      "BinCode": "M1-F-01-A1-01",
      "OnHandQty": "250"
    },
    {
      "AbsEntry": 7,
      "BinCode": "M1-F-01-A1-02",
      "OnHandQty": "250"
    }
  ]
}
```

If you want a cleaner solution you should write two views:

1. The first view with the "root" elements:

   - ItemCode
   - ItemName
   - CodeBars
   - WhsCode
2. the second view with "children" elements:

   - AbsEntry
   - BinCode
   - OnHandQty

then you can `JOIN` these views and extract the JSON as in the previous example.

Here is the complete code I used for the *quick & dirty* solution:

```
if OBJECT_ID('OIBQ') is not null drop TABLE OIBQ
if OBJECT_ID('OITM') is not null drop TABLE OITM
if OBJECT_ID('OBIN') is not null drop TABLE OBIN
go
CREATE TABLE OIBQ(ItemCode varchar(50), OnHandQty varchar(50), WhsCode  varchar(50), BinAbs int)
CREATE TABLE OITM(ItemCode varchar(50), ItemName  varchar(50), CodeBars varchar(50))
CREATE TABLE OBIN(AbsEntry int        , BinCode   varchar(50), BinAbs   int)
go
insert into OIBQ values
     ('NEWZTN109314',-2,'M1',1)
    ,('NEWZTN109314',250,'M1',6)
    ,('NEWZTN109314',250,'M1',7)
insert into OITM values 
    ('NEWZTN109314','STAFFA SGNACIO RAPIDO ANTENNA NAV900','2000000100227')
insert into OBIN values
     (1, 'M1-SYSTEM-BIN-LOCATION', -2)
    ,(6, 'M1-F-01-A1-01', 250) 
    ,(7, 'M1-F-01-A1-02', 250)
go
if OBJECT_ID('MyVie') is not null
drop VIEW MyVie
go
CREATE VIEW MyVie( AbsEntry,
     BinCode,
     ItemCode,
     ItemName,
     CodeBars,
     OnHandQty,
     WhsCode ) AS SELECT
 OBIN.AbsEntry,
     OBIN.BinCode,
     OIBQ.ItemCode,
     OITM.ItemName,
     OITM.CodeBars,
     OIBQ.OnHandQty,
     OIBQ.WhsCode 
FROM OBIN 
    INNER JOIN OIBQ ON OBIN.AbsEntry=OIBQ.BinAbs 
    INNER JOIN OITM ON OITM.ItemCode=OIBQ.ItemCode
go
select A.ItemCode, A.ItemName, A.CodeBars, A.WhsCode, 
       Bin.AbsEntry, Bin.BinCode, Bin.OnHandQty
from MyVie A 
inner join MyVie Bin on A.AbsEntry = Bin.AbsEntry and A.BinCode = Bin.BinCode and A.ItemCode = Bin.ItemCode
for json auto, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```